# Combine/Merge two ggplot aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

Let's say I have two ggplot aesthetics:

```
a.1 <- aes(v.1=1, v.2=2)
a.2 <- aes(v.3=3)
```

Is there a way to combine the already built aesthetics? In my example it would be something like:

```
a.merged <- aes(v.1=2, v.2=2,v.3=3)
```

I know that aes_string can be used to build an aesthetic from a character vector, that can be concatenated, but I am looking at the case where the two aesthetics are already built and I want to avoid having to convert them to characters first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
> c(a.1,a.2)
$v.1
[1] 1

$v.2
[1] 2

$v.3
[1] 3
```

`aes` objects are "unevaluated expressions" and the `c()` function works as expected, depending on your definition of "expected". To be safe you probably need to add back the class that gets stripped by `c()`:

```
a.merged <- c(a.1,a.2)
class(a.merged) <- "uneval"
```

If you want to do it in one step then the function `modifyList` will not strip the "name"-less attributes:

```
> modifyList(a.1, a.2)
List of 3
 $ v.1: num 1
 $ v.2: num 2
 $ v.3: num 3
> attributes(modifyList(a.1, a.2))
$names
[1] "v.1" "v.2" "v.3"

$class
[1] "uneval"
```

Comment: I see, I tried c() before but didn't realize i could just simply add back the class. Thanks!

Comment: In ggplot2 version 2.2.1 it appears to be necessary to use `modifyList`. Just using `c()` results in an error: "Mapping must be created by aes() or aes_()".

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)

a.1 <- aes(v.1=1, v.2=2)
a.2 <- aes(v.3=3)

modifyList(a.1, a.2)
```

```
Aesthetic mapping: 
* `v.1` -> 1
* `v.2` -> 2
* `v.3` -> 3
```

`modifyList` doesn't mutate its arguments, despite the name. Thanks to [Simon.S.A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7742981/simon-s-a) for suggesting this approach [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084380/435004).